# Where do flip flops "save" their state?

Tags: flipflop

From what I could understand, the state of a flip flop is the current value it is holding on to, i.e., the value that was previously inputted and is now saved for future use. My question is, where does it actually save that state? and how does it know?

Comment: Have you done any research into this already? Why do you think there needs to be a "where" at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the flip-flop is stored as the voltage on a particular signal node inside the flip-flop. This voltage is maintained by using a positive feedback loop within the circuit. When the appropriate input conditions are applied to change the state of the flip-flop this positive feedback loop is broken and the new value is stored (by changing the voltage on the particular node).

Comment: You may want to clarify that in most flip-flops that there are generally two nodes of voltage that hold the state that are held at opposing voltage levels, one high and the other low and these opposing levels flip when the flip-flop changes to store the opposite level.